# Question on Replacement for NEMA34 Step Motor

Tags: stepper-motor

I have access to an old CNC router that uses HY200 3424 stepper motors (NEMA 34, [pdf](http://www.ad.siemens.com.cn/club/bbs/upload/file/20170531/6363187097941910273468377.pdf)). They are rated 4.7 A, 90 Volt and 150/193 Nm. I would like to run them with a CNC xPro, or similar. I would like to understand how to decide on a possible replacement and what specifications that I need to look for.

Will either of the steppers below work if I can get the shaft to fit?

- [Dual Shaft Nema 34 Stepper Motor Unipolar 1.8 deg 2.2Nm (312oz.in) 2A 86x86x66mm 6 Wires](https://www.oyostepper.com/goods-97-Dual-Shaft-Nema-34-Stepper-Motor-Unipolar-18-deg-22Nm-312ozin-2A-86x86x66mm-6-Wires.html)
- [Nema 34 Bipolar 1.8deg 4.5 Nm(637.38oz.in) 6.0A 86x86x74mm 4 Wires](https://www.oyostepper.com/goods-511-Nema-34-Bipolar-18deg-45-Nm-63738ozin-60A-86x86x74mm-4-Wires.html)

If not, what parameters do I need to be looking at to decide which motor I should buy?

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* huanyingkou, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so I have edited your question to ask how you can work out for yourself what to buy. While Stack Exchange is a forum in the sense that we are a community which shares ideas, we aren't a discussion forum, we are a community where we can ask and answer questions.